# Determine which clock of a compound sensitivity list triggered always block

Tags: verilog, simulation, system-verilog, testbench, fifo

I am trying to implement a non-synthesizable dual-clock FIFO in Verilog (solely for testbench purposes). Since the FIFO has to operate correctly even when both clocks toggle precisely at the same moment, I want to arrange its logic into the single `always` block with both clocks in its sensitivity list. Remembering that VHDL has `'event` syntax, I wrote something like this:

```
integer memoryOccupiedBits = 0;

always @(resetAsync, posedge readClock, posedge writeClock) begin
    if (resetAsync) begin
        ...
        memoryOccupiedBits = 0;
        ...
    end else begin
        if ((posedge readClock) && readClockEnable) begin
            if (readEnable) begin
                ...
                memoryOccupiedBits = memoryOccupiedBits - ReadPortWidth;
                `Assert(memoryOccupiedBits >= 0);
                ...
            end
        end

        if ((posedge writeClock) && writeClockEnable) begin
            if (writeEnable) begin
                ...
                memoryOccupiedBits = memoryOccupiedBits + WritePortWidth;
                `Assert(memoryOccupiedBits <= TotalDepthBits);
                ...
            end
        end
    end
end
```

However, this usage of `posedge clock` is not allowed in Verilog (at least my simulator says it is a syntax error). Is there any language construct to achieve the result of VHDL's `'event`? Or some other way to rewrite the above code without sacrificing its clarity and structure?

**UPD:**
I added some more details to my code snippet to clarify the intent. Please note the blocking assignments to the `memoryOccupiedBits` signal.

Answer (score 2):

Since this does not need to be synthesizable, you could separate this logic into separate `always` blocks

```
always @(resetAsync)
    if (resetAsync) begin
        ...
    end
always @(posedge readClock iff !resetAsync && readClockEnable)
    if (readEnable) begin
                ...
    end
always @(posedge writeClock iff !resetAsync && writeClockEnable)
    if (writeEnable) begin
                ...
    end
```

### Updated

Based on the new information provided, you can use nonblocking event triggers and the `triggered()` method to see if one or both clocks were triggered.

````
  event r_ev,w_ev
  always @(posedge readClock) ->>r_ev;
  always @(posedge writeClock) ->>w_ev;
  
  always @(r_ev or w_ev) 
    if (r_ev.triggered && w_ev.triggered)
      $display($time,,"both r_ev and w_ev");
    else if (r_ev.triggered)
      $display($time,,"r_ev triggered");
    else if (w_ev.triggered)
      $display($time,,"w_ev triggered");
    else
      $display($time,,"unreachable");
```
````

Comment: Unfortunately, if you separate the logic into different `always` blocks, you cannot reason about the order they are to be executed in if both clocks triggered at the same moment.

Comment: You added new requirements to your original question. In discrete event simulation, no two events ever happen at the same moment. You can only _know_ that the two clocks triggered when the scheduled event region is over.

Answer (score 0):

`posedge` is legal in the sensitivity list `@(...)`, but it is illegal inside the body of the `always` block.  This code compiles without syntax errors:

```
always @(resetAsync, posedge readClock, posedge writeClock) begin
    if (resetAsync) begin
    end else begin
        if (readClock && readClockEnable) begin
            if (readEnable) begin
            end
        end

        if (writeClock && writeClockEnable) begin
            if (writeEnable) begin
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that code does a different thing (actually, I wrote my code like this at first). Imagine one clock being exactly twice as fast as the other. In this case one of the `if`s will false-positively execute at the middle of its clock cycle.

Answer (score 0):

It seems I have found a workaround, though it does not look very clean or elegant. The point is to save clock values on each `always` block invocation and manually detect clock edges:

````vhdl
reg readClockPrev = 1'b0;
reg writeClockPrev = 1'b0;

wire readClockPosedge = ({readClockPrev, readClock} === 2'b01);
wire writeClockPosedge = ({writeClockPrev, writeClock} === 2'b01);

always @(resetAsync, readClock, writeClock) begin
    if (resetAsync) begin
        ...
    end else begin
        if (readClockPosedge && readClockEnable) begin
            if (readEnable) begin
                ...
            end
        end

        if (writeClockPosedge && writeClockEnable) begin
            if (writeEnable) begin
                ...
            end
        end
    end

    readClockPrev = readClock;
    writeClockPrev = writeClock;
end
```
````

Comment: There is no guarantee the `always` block executes  only once if both clocks have their `posedge` in the same timestep.